# Remove words with a length of maximum 2. Spark

Tags: replace, hive, sparklyr

I want to remove (or replace with a non-blank value) all words of a length less than 2 in `sparklyr`.

My attempt is below, but doesn't work:

```
Tab8b <- tab8 %>% Ft_sql_transformer(
              sql="select * , 
              Regexp_replace(VAR, '\b[a-z_]{1,2}\b',' ') as VAR2
              from __THIS__ ")
```

Comment: `\\b` ..........................

Comment: Thank you. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: It works. \\b is in hive. \\\\b is in R-spark